# Capistrano - clean up old releases

Tags: capistrano

Usually when using capistrano, I will go and manually delete old releases from a deployed application. I understand that you can run `cap deploy:cleanup` but that still leaves 5 releases. Is this it's intended purpose? Is there another way to cleanup old releases to just 1 previous deploy?

Comment: it's ever a good idea to keep some previous releases, then if you last deploy contains a big mistake you can fast rollback with capistrano (cap deploy:rollback) to the previous release until you fix it.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can use the `:keep_releases` variable to override the default of 5.  Check [this](http://geoff.evason.name/2009/03/27/setting-a-capistrano-variable-from-the-command-line/) out.

Comment: May be worth noting that even if the find+rm command fails to remove some files the task seems to silently "succeed" when called via the `after` hook. Calling it directly shows the errors... I realized this when I was starting to run out of disk space.

Comment: @Josh You accepted this answer, but you should check if you have set the callback for "deploy:cleanup" as I said below, since it don't run by default.

Answer (score 134):

You could do this automatically by setting this in your deploy.rb

```
set :keep_releases, 1
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"
```

In the past(I don't know exactly which version) this callback was the default, but later the developer decided to leave it to the user to decide. In capistrano 3 it was added back to the default deploy flow.

Comment: Thank you, Diego. Your answer works correctly in Capistrano v2.14.1.

Comment: Looks like [Capistrano 3 calls `deploy:cleanup` as part of the deploy flow](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/690afc0c5c3c43d2920b0bfdeb9323c286b12106/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake#L23).

Answer (score 42):

If you want to delete all releases except the last 3 for example you can run:

```
cap deploy:cleanup -s keep_releases=3
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `optionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: s`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to keep the 5 releases for normal deployments but needed for certain situations to be able to remove all previous releases.

I was able to do this with a custom task. Create a file `lib/capistrano/tasks/cleanup.rake` and add the following code.

```
desc "Remove all but the last release"
task :cleanup_all do
    set :keep_releases, 1
    invoke "deploy:cleanup"
end
```

To run use `bundle exec cap staging cleanup_all` or `cap staging cleanup_all`