# How to maintain older releases of application which capistrano cloned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I would like to prune older versions of my application under `releases` folder to just maintain the last 5 versions of my application. Currently it contains a lot of releases from the beginning. I don't want do this manually by doing a remote login and remove older folders, but would like it automated as part of `Capfile`, how should I do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capistrano - clean up old releases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121957/capistrano-clean-up-old-releases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `config/deploy.rb` you can set `:keep_releases` option

```
set :keep_releases, 5
```

Comment: in addition, you can also use `cap deploy:cleanup` to delete the older releases.