# How to setup the development environment using cap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I would like to run cap development deploy:setup and cap development deploy to setup the dev environment for my rails app. In order to do this, I will have to remove the project folder from the remote machine, is there a way to automate this in some fashion using cap.

I basically want to remove the app folder in remote machine before I do a full deploy.

Comment: why you should do that? if something happens during your deploy, you do not have an old release..I think this really does not make sense anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Capistrano app folder is structured like this:

- `releases` - Contains separate folders (named using commit IDs or timestamps) for each deployment made so far
- `current` - Linked to the latest deployment folder under `releases`
- `shared` - Shared logs, gem files, and `tmp` which are used between deployments

Now do you really want to clean the entire app folder? That could be dangerous since you'll lose logs.

`current` is just a symbolic link, it points to the latest release only.

If you want to clean up old releases, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121957/capistrano-clean-up-old-releases). You can set `keep_releases` to 1.

If you want to delete the shared folder as well, then you have to write your own Capistrano hook as @Strik3r mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
before 'deploy:setup', 'removecode'

task :removecode do
    run "rm -rf <path>", :shell => fetch(:rvm_shell)
end
```

add this code in to your deploy.rb file, this will call before deploy:setup
in this way you can create a task and do what ever you want to do

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: you can list all task using `cap -vT`